# Are git branches squashed or replayed when merging?

Tags: git, github, merge

Given a repo with a master and a feature branch and commits `C0` through `C5` as below:

```
C0 <-- C1 <-- C2 <------ ???   master
       \                /
        C3 <-- C4 <-- C5      feature
```

When I merge, what happens at the `???` point?

Do I get one commit `C6`, i.e. a "squash" of the merge as a single commit:

```
C0 <-- C1 <-- C2 <------ C6    master
       \                /
        C3 <-- C4 <-- C5      feature
```

Or a "replay", i.e. `C6 <-- C3' <-- C4' <-- C5'` (with the `'` because these commits now also contain `C2`):

```
C0 <-- C1 <-- C2 <------ C6 <-- C3' <-- C4' <-- C5'   master
       \                /
        C3 <-- C4 <-- C5                              feature
```

Is it the same on GitHub when merging a box-standard pull request from the same repo's branch?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Also, a "squash" is the collapsing of history, since you're not getting rid of history, you're not squashing. A commit is simply a snapshot of what the repository looks like at that point, a merge is one way to create such a commit by integrating two sets of changes and forming a new snapshot.

Comment: Neither of both happens. You get the difference from C5 to C1 and C2 to C1.

Comment: I don't see how merging could replay all those commits on top of `master`.  That could only happen from a fast-forward, which isn't possible in your example, or maybe by some sort of rebase.

Comment: I checked on our project's history on github, and it looks like replay - but the manual always depicts it like a [squash](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) (replay, then commit), so I'm confused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does 'git merge' work in details?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961255/how-does-git-merge-work-in-details)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you get is neither a squash nor a replay of the commits.

To get a squash you could use the `--squash` option to `merge`.  Then you'd get

```
C0 <-- C1 <-- C2 <-- C3C4C5   master
       \                
        C3 <-- C4 <-- C5      feature
```

where `C3C4C5` is a single commit with one parent whose diff from `C2` is equal to `C5`s diff from `C1` (barring conflicts).

The replay the changes from the branch, you could perform a rebasing operation.  This might yield

```
C0 <-- C1 <-- C2 <-- C3' <-- C4' <-- C5'   master    featurE_ref
       \                
        C3 <-- C4 <-- C5      feature_ref_used_to_be_here
```

(or some variation, depending exactly what you do).  In this case commit `C3'` differs form `C2` exactly as `C3` differs form `C1`, etc.

But in the case of a merge you don't get either of those. You get

```
C0 <-- C1 <-- C2 <------ M     master
       \                /
        C3 <-- C4 <-- C5      feature
```

'M' is a single commit, but unlike a `C3C4C5` from the squash, `M` has two parents.  Its `TREE` (content) differs from `C2` in the same way that `C5`s `TREE` differs form `C1`, so it's *similar* to a squash.  But it generally is interpreted as not introducing changes (except in the case of merge conflicts or evil merges); rather it marks that the changes from `C5` and its ancestors are introduced into `master` at this point.  Hence by default `git log` doesn't display a patch for `M` but does include commits `C3`, `C4`, and `C5`

Answer (score 3):

Supposing you use the command `git merge` **without** the `--squash` option, what happens is that Git creates a `C6` commit, called a `merge commit`, which is a like a **snapshot** of your tracked files after merging their contents. The default strategy is the recursive, which merges by taking into account what changed between `C5` and `C1`, and between `C2` and `C1`.

Since this is a merge commit, its parent would be `C5` and `C2`.

Your confusion probably comes from the fact that you are not considering what commits are: they are just pointers to a state of a tree of files. They don't store differences (let's skip compression done by the gc for simplicity), they store **states**. So Git would merge your files, save them, hash them and create a single hash (representing a tree object) that allows us to reconstruct that state, which is what your `C6` commit will point to. [Git From The Inside Out](https://codewords.recurse.com/issues/two/git-from-the-inside-out) does a wonderful job at explaining this whole process.

If, on the other hand, you had used `git merge --squash`, Git would also create a commit with the state after the merge, but the resulting commit would be like a normal commit, without two parents. See [Git: To squash or not to squash?](http://jamescooke.info/git-to-squash-or-not-to-squash.html) for more information.

Finally, this "replaying" process is done by `rebase`, but not in the way you described. Read [Merging vs. Rebasing](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing) to see how `merge` and `rebase` differ.

Answer (score 1):

You get neither of both....directly.

First of all a merge in git is working like this:

1. Find the common ancestor of both heads, in your case this is `C1`
2. Merge the both heads in terms of 'find the difference between those and the common ancestor and put it together, wherever I am not able to do this deterministic I am asking the user`
3. As I am finished I create a new commit, the merge commit, which has `C2` and `C5` as a common parent

You can ofcourse squash (`git merge --squash`) when you merge. This is explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43551395/4849573) excellent answer.