# How to get content of another dev branch into my dev branch

Tags: git

I have a `master` branch. Under it, I have one branch `dev`. Under `dev`, I have two different branches, `library` and `application`. This `library` branch has code which can be used by multiple applications in that future, so the development of that is kept separately. Is there a way to refer to that branch in my `application` branch? I mean, what is the best way to get content of `library` branch into my `application` branch?

Comment: (psst, you don't have branches "under" another) --- also, I think you're asking about merging

Comment: [How 'git merge' works in details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24808093/7976758).

Answer (score 0):

This is not the purpose of branches. Branches are for storing concurrent paths of development of the *same* code, not for storing *different* code in the same repository. You should instead have two repositories, one for the library and one for the application; or put both in separate directories in the same branch of the same repository.

Answer (score 0):

@Adrian has reason in the purpose of branches.
But if you want to do that (something I don't recommend), you can do:

1. Save your branch changes:

   ```
   git add . (or what you need to add)
   git commit
   ```
2. Merge your branch

   ```
   git merge library
   ```