# No conflicts when merging two branches that have differing .csv files

Tags: git, github

My colleagues and I have just started learning how to collaborate on GitHub.
I have been using it for a while, but just on my own for now. When playing around as a team to try and understand some of the processes we stumbled upon an odd problem.

Forgive the visuals below, here are the branches we had:

```
main ---- raw csv ---- clean csv|
                       newBranch --- analyse clean|
```

And this is what we did next:

```
main ---- raw csv ---- clean csv --- delete column in raw csv  ---| merge => No conflicts
                       newBranch --- analyse clean --- --- --- ---|
```

In other words, someone deleted a column in the original raw csv on the *main* branch, with the deletion being tracked by git and successfully committed. However, when merging *newBranch* with the *main*, there should have been a conflict where the raw csv from *main* does not match with the raw csv from *newBranch*, but there was no conflict. The merge was successful and the deleted column from the main was still there.

The raw was in a subfolder, and I looked into .git/info/exclude but everything was default.
Any idea why this is happening? Is there a reason why the changes made were tracked but no conflicts were found?

Answer (score 0):

Hope both file_name and file_location is the same in both branches. Otherwise git will not track that as a change in the same file.

When git merge happens, for example raw.csv, git walk through the change blocks identified in the two diffs.

- If both sides of the file have the same change in the same spot,
  accept either one.
- if one introduces a change and the other leaves
  that region alone, introduce the change in the final.
- if both introduce changes in a spot, but they don't match, mark a conflict to
  be resolved manually.

In your scenario, delete columns won't introduce changes in same spot. So no merge conflict.

checkout this links for further details.
[How does 'git merge' work in details?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961255/how-does-git-merge-work-in-details)