# how does merge works in repository?

Tags: git

I accidentally committed and pushed my changes and also `node_modules` into a remote branch.

So, to fix, I tried rebase by doing: (Don't mind if I didn't include in the steps adding node_modules into gitignore since I did it in separate process)

1. git log
2. git reset "to the commit that includes the node_modules"
3. git add "only the files that needed to be committed and pushed"
4. git status ***(node_modules are now unstaged)***
5. git commit -m "remove node_modules"
6. git push -f

Now its working as expected (to commit and push my changes), if I pull request, it says no conflict with master.

But I'm curious as to how merge works, does it also merge the commit which includes node_modules, or will it just merge the latest commit ?

Because my goal is to only merge to master the newest commit that excludes the node_modules and ignore the commit that includes the node_modules

Comment: See also [How does 'git merge' work in details?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14961255/1256452) (not exactly a duplicate; there are duplicates but I was not able to find one quickly)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the difference between your branch and `master` for example with:

```
git fetch origin
git log --oneline origin/master..<your_branch>
```

This will show the commits that are present in your local branch and are not present in origin/master