# How to Prevent PRs from Removing Commits

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I noticed that PRs on Stash don't show if old commits have been removed.

e.g:

1. make a new branch
2. `$git reset HEAD~100 --hard && git clean -f && touch mango` to remove 100 commits and add a file making the PR look like it has some changes
3. `$git commit -m "Added mango" && git push -f`
4. setup a PR from that branch
   The above on Stash would just show that a file "Mango" has been added and completely ignore the 100 missing commits

Are there good ways to avoid this issue besides hoping none of the developers are malicious?
and do PRs on GitHub have the same issue?

Comment: PRs are only additive by nature. They can delete source code, but they can't remove commits from history. As such, this question doesn't make sense. **Merging a PR that doesn't contain some history doesn't undo that history**, because a merge performs... well, a _merge_ operation: it combines the new content from the PR with what's already in the repo; it doesn't _overwrite_ the repo's contents with that of the PR.

Comment: (That said, note that a github PR is a _github_ construct, not a _git_ construct; these are different things, tagging should be according -- though merge semantics are provided by git itself, not github or stash).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's predicated on a counterfactual: The problem it poses doesn't exist.

Comment: oops, I was thinking that PRs were a feature of git. and for the tags, I wasnt able to add a stash tag because it's not an existing tag

Comment: The original workflow for git repositories where not all committers have direct write access to a shared repository (or publicly reachable git repositories of their own) didn't involve any website like github or stash at all -- there's a `git format-patch` operation that makes a bunch of emails you can send to a mailing list, and a corresponding operation to apply/merge the content you received in email locally; what's now a "pull request" used to be a series of mailing list posts.

Comment: BTW, what exactly _is_ it you're referring to as "stash"? It's a hard term to search for, [tag:git-stash] being a common term of art in the git world that means something else.

Comment: I was referring to Atlassian Bitbucket

Comment: Ah! _That_ we have a tag for. :)

Comment: To try to explain a little better about how a merge works -- in the simplest cases, git looks for the oldest shared commit between the history between the PR and the destination branch, and takes the delta _between that shared commit and the tip of the PR_ and tries to apply that as a patch. So in your scenario it'll identify `HEAD~100` as the shared history point, see that the only diff from there is creating the `mango` file, and thus will try to add the `mango` file on top of the old head when your PR is merged.

Comment: (Even the above is an oversimplification; see [What is git merge doing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961255/what-is-git-merge-doing) for a better explanation -- but the important point is that it _doesn't_ just replace the old tip with the new one, and old commits won't disappear).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, you have to try to think like the computer - forget what *you* know you did, and look at what the end result is.

You had a history like this:

```
a99 - a100 - a101 - ... - a199 - a200 <- branch A
```

You created a new branch:

```
a99 - a100 - a101 - ... - a199 - a200 <- branch A
                                   ^- branch B
```

Then you "removed" 100 commits from branch B, by resetting it back to an earlier point in history - but you didn't touch branch A:

```
a99 - a100 - a101 - ... - a199 - a200 <- branch A
        ^- branch B
```

And you added a commit:

```
a99 - a100 - a101 - ... - a199 - a200 <- branchA
          \
           b1
            ^- branchB
```

Looking at that diagram, it's hopefully clear that there's no record of "removing" anything. You would have exactly the same diagram if you'd got as far as commit a100, created branch B, and then left it lying around while you created another 100 commits on branch A.

That's exactly what git is designed to assume - that the branches diverged not because someone wants to *remove* something, but because two different people (or the same person working on two different features) wants to *combine* two sets of changes. So when you merge them together - whether via a Pull Request / Merge Request UI, or just directly in a local clone - it will simply try to apply the changes between a100 and b1 on top of a200, and create this:

```
a99 - a100 - a101 - ... - a199 - a200 - a201<- branchA
          \                              /
           b1 ---------------------------
            ^- branchB
```

You actually have to go a long way out of your way to *remove* part of the history in git, because the commits themselves are immutable. All you can really do is point a branch at an alternative line of commits, and shared UIs like GitHub, Gitlab, and BitBucket have settings for who is allowed to do that to which branch.

Comment: I think it's better to call it "went back 100 commits" instead of "removed 100 commits"

Comment: @Steve It is indeed. The commits would only be "removed" if this was the only branch or tag referring to them, at which point they would be identified as "unreachable" and git would "garbage collect" them at some point in the future.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize Charles's comments, this is not an issue because PRs will not remove commits because they are just merge that need approval before completing.

The example above that removes 100 commits, adds 1 commit, and then sets up a PR should just add that 1 commit and maybe cause a merge conflict if necessary